# Compare primal solution and dual solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I'm having trouble comparing primal solution and dual problem from the semidefinite program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 2x_1\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 5x_1 & 0 \\ 5 x_1 & 3x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 x_1 \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0\end{array}$$

I can't seem to find how to compare two solutions.

Comment: Your semidefinite program does not make sense. Perhaps you left out some information?